# Show single record from mysql query database

Tags: php

Firstly, im sorry for my bad english and i am new ini php code.
I am having some problem with my php code. I have some data like this:

```
name tabel : db_phone  
**|PHONE_OS|PHONE |TOTAL|**  
|WINDOWS |LUMIA_1 | 5 |  
|WINDOWS |LUMIA_1 | 2 |  
|WINDOWS |LUMIA_2 | 2 |  
|ANDROID |NEXUS_1 | 4 |   
|ANDROID |NEXUS_2 | 5 |  
|ANDROID |NEXUS_2 | 2 |  
|ANDROID |NEXUS_2 | 3 |
```

my question is :
how to show only one data if it double or more than one.
what should i do if i will make some print out in php like this format:

```
**|PHONE_OS|PHONE |TOTAL|**  
|WINDOWS |LUMIA_1 | 5 |  
|__________|_______ | 2 |  
|__________|LUMIA_2 | 2 |  
|ANDROID |NEXUS_1 | 4 |   
|_________|NEXUS_2 | 5 |  
|_________|________| 2 |  
|_________|________| 3 |
```

Thanks before,
yahz

Comment: You may search to check the php function `preg_split` on the web

Comment: Can you please add some code snippet or query you are using to get the results?

Comment: too broad and unclear; post your code

Comment: This is next to "MySQL 101". You need to put some effort into this and try something.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do this by `GROUP BY` clause. The GROUP BY statement is used in conjunction with the aggregate functions to group the result-set by one or more columns.

Your possible sql query may be like this:

```
SELECT * FROM db_phone GROUP BY PHONE_OS
```

We have here grouped them which have same `PHONE_OS` values.
 You can add more columns like this:

```
SELECT * FROM db_phone GROUP BY PHONE_OS, PHONE
```

In this query you have grouped them which have same `PHONE_OS` and same `PHONE` values.

Comment: Thanks for your answer sir. I found example code in this question : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29592836/creating-a-dynamic-table-with-rowspan-php. But how if more than one column like my data?

Comment: @alyazid I have updated answer. It can be done by simply adding more column names

Comment: Yes sir.Thank you so much..it done.

Comment: I am happy I am of your help.